# Array unique values

Tags: javascript, json, yql

While dealing with JSON returned from YQL, I found myself looking for a way extract all unique values from an array.

```
function uniqueArrayValues(o){
      var items = o.query.results.row,
          output = [];

  function check(val){
    for(var c=0; c<output.length; c++){
      if(output[c] === val){
        return false;
        }
    }
     return true;
  }

 for(var i=1; i<items.length; i++){
   if(check(items[i].team)){
     output.push(items[i].team);
    }    
  }

  return output;
}
```

The code looks a bit too 'busy' and i was wondering if there is a more elegant way of extracting unique values from an array.

Comment: You can filter to unique values within the YQL query, if that is an option for you. See http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/sorting.html --- something like `| unique(field="row.team")` (the field maybe different, depending on the result structure).

Comment: That would work if i only needed the unique values,  but i am extracting these values from an object that is already on the client side (I only make one YQL request).

Comment: @Q, fair enough. [eskimoblood's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308257/array-unique-values/3308650#3308650) answer should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf to check if an element is in an array.

```
 function check(val){
        return output.indexOf(val) != -1;
    }
```

or use an object instead of an array if you have an unique id or name: 
var output = {}

```
for(var i=1; i<items.length; i++){
   if(!output[items[i].team.id])){
     output [items[i].team.id] = items[i].team;
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your array has non-trivial length, the standard way to extract unique elements is to sort or to hash the array.

EDIT: Some pseudo code

```
sort array
last = unused
for each v in array do
  if v != last
     uniqueArray.push_back(v)
     last = v
  end if
end for
// uniqueArray now contains the unique elements of array
```