# How to make a JSON array unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308257/array-unique-values)
>   [Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery)

Im having a JSON string like this

```
[
 Object { id="38",product="foo"},
 Object { id="38",product="foo"},
 Object { id="38",product="foo"},
 Object { id="39",product="bar"},
 Object { id="40",product="hello"},
 Object { id="40",product="hello"}

]
```

There are duplicate values in this JSON array..how can i make this JSON array unique like this

```
[
 Object { id="38",product="foo"},
 Object { id="39",product="bar"},
 Object { id="40",product="hello"}
]
```

.Im looking for a suggestion that uses less iterations,
`Jquery $.inArray` is not working in this case.

Suggestion to use any third party libraries are welcome.

Comment: Would you like to remove elements with the same id/product combination or just with the same id?

Comment: The most efficient way to do that is to turn the array into a hash with elements as keys. Then turn the hash into an array. Should give you `O(n)`.

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with JSON at all ;)

Comment: so how do you do it @TorstenWalter ..any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: I have answered below :) I was referring to the tag `JSON`. Whether the `array` comes from a `JSON` string, is entered manually or generated by JavaScript code is irrelevant for the intended task, which is to filter the array so it only contains distinct values. I don't mean to bash, just try to educate.

Comment: One-liner Solution:
const uniqueProduct = [... new Set(productArr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the solution in the following SO question:

[Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery)

You'll have to iterate through your array and create a new array which contains unique values.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [underscore's uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

In your case, you need to provide an iterator to extract 'id':

```
array = _.uniq(array, true /* array already sorted */, function(item) {
  return item.id;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Assuming first that you had **_valid json_**
myList= [
    { "id":"38","product":"foo"},
    { "id":"38","product":"foo"},
    { "id":"38","product":"foo"},
    { "id":"39","product":"bar"},
    { "id":"40","product":"hello"},
    { "id":"40","product":"hello"}
];

// What you're essentially attempting to do is turn this **list of objects** into a **dictionary**.
var newDict = {}

for(var i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
    newDict[myList[i]['id']] = myList[i]['product'];
}

// `newDict` is now:
console.log(newDict);
```

Comment: This is good if you need the data in key value pairs. However, if you need the keys as they are, say for a template, this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to loop through removing the duplicates. If the items stored are in order as you have suggested, it's a simple matter of a single loop:

```
function removeDuplicates(arrayIn) {
    var arrayOut = [];
    for (var a=0; a < arrayIn.length; a++) {
        if (arrayOut[arrayOut.length-1] != arrayIn[a]) {
            arrayOut.push(arrayIn[a]);
        }
    }
    return arrayOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily code this yourself.
From the top of my head this comes to mind.

```
var filtered = $.map(originalArray, function(item) {
    if (filtered.indexOf(item) <= 0) {
        return item;
    }
});
```

Or as suggested a more efficient algorithm specifically for the case at hand:

```
var helper = {};
var filtered = $.map(originalArray, function(val) {
    var id = val.id;

    if (!filtered[id]) {
        helper[id] = val;
        return val;
    }
});
helper = null;
```

Comment: Quite inefficient. In worst scenario `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If the data returned really has the ids, then of course a hash map with id keys would be the most efficient.

Comment: +1: Exactly. If the OP wants an array, then he can easily convert `filtered` into an array. This solution should be `O(n)` in terms of computational complexity although uses at least twice as much memory. Shouldn't be a problem, though ( who would send such big JSONs to client side anyway? ).

Comment: Memory should not be significantly more since the object and array contain only references to the same objects.