# Using underscore unique on object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to return a unique array where the room object is the same.

```
var input = [
  {
    position:{
      room: {
        name: 'WC',
        number: '001'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    position:{
      room: {
        name: 'WC',
        number: '001'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    position:{
      room: {
        name: 'RWC',
        number: '007'
      }
    }
  }
];
```

So this list would be:

```
var input = [
  {
    position:{
      room: {
        name: 'WC',
        number: '001'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    position:{
      room: {
        name: 'RWC',
        number: '007'
      }
    }
  }
];
```

I tried this:

```
  var distinctRooms = _.uniq(input, function(input){
    return input.position.room
  });
```

But it returns the entire list. Have not seen any example where you compare objects. Is this possible to do somehow with the _uniq?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As long as you don't have circular structures, you can use JSON Stringify to make a deep comparison of every room attribute

```
_.uniq(input, function(input){
    return JSON.stringify(input.position.room)
  });
```

Comment: Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order.

Comment: You're right. I guess you could extract the object keys and use _.sort to provide a sorted copy. It seems like a lot of overkill :(

Comment: Isn't there a badge for a -1 rated accepted answer? ¬¬

Comment: There should be one for creating a Heisenbug. :)

Comment: @amenadiel, haha, I don't really what you are talking about but your  code works as expected.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko whoa I there's a concept I hadn't heard of!

Comment: @user1572526 Beware that you are relying on undefined behaviour. :) `var isAlive = JSON.stringify({name: 1, number: 2}) === JSON.stringify({number: 2, name: 1})` - is pure quantum mechanics. :)

Comment: A reasonable bet would be to `return input.position.room.name + input.position.room.number`

Answer (score 1):

Room objects are different. If you consider rooms to be equal based on their numbers you can use

```
  var distinctRooms = _.uniq(input, function(input){
    return input.position.room.number;
  });
```

Comment: that would discard rooms with matching numbers, even if names were different, which isn't what OP is asking

Comment: @amenadiel How do you know OP has rooms with the same numbers but different names? :) Sounds like a nonusual case to me.

Comment: it's a gift I've had since childhood ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826353/1455133) where he iterates and creates an array with unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`_.isEqual()` function](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) that provides deep object comparison it is possible to create a function that applies it to an array of objects and create a mix-in from that function.

Algorithm:

1. take the first element from the list (the *head*), store it in the result
2. iterate the rest of the list (the *tail*), remove every element that `.isEqual` to the first element
3. if the rest of the list is not empty, pass it to step 1, otherwise return the result

Code, implemented with a recursive approach:

```
_.mixin({
    deepUniq: (function () {
        var dedup = function (coll, result) {
            var head = _.first(coll),
                tail = _.reject(_.rest(coll), function (curr) {
                    return _.isEqual(curr, head);
                });

            result.push(head);
            return (tail.length) ? dedup(tail, result) : result;
        };
        return function (coll) {
            return dedup(coll, []);
        };
    })()
});
```

A word of warning: This approach has exponential running time, i.e. it will be increasingly slow for long lists of deeply nested objects. My advice would be to compare correctness and performance of different solutions.

---

Disclaimer: This solution is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19641747/