# How to make a JSON array unique without sorting using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, duplicates

I am working with JSON that is something like as follows in Javascript:

```
{
"data": [
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Zeta",
      "unit": "456456456",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Alpha",
      "unit": "345345",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Maverick",
      "unit": "453455",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Delta",
      "unit": 3534545"",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Delta",
      "unit": 3534545"",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Bravo",
      "unit": "534553455",
},
 {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Bravo",
      "unit": "534553455",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Bravo",
      "unit": "4356346436",
}
]
}
```

I want to be able to make this JSON unique via the name value, so for example I want to be able to parse the and change the JSON so it becomes like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Zeta",
      "unit": "456456456",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Alpha",
      "unit": "345345",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Maverick",
      "unit": "453455",
},
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Delta",
      "unit": 3534545"",
},
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Data Point Bravo",
      "unit": "453455",
},
]
}
```

So I am retrieving the first unique instance of an object based on its name. I need to do so using basic Javascript, I can't use JQuery or any other libraries. And I don't want to have to sort the array.

I have already tried following code from the following questions but with no luck:

[How to make a JSON array unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826302/how-to-make-a-json-array-unique)

[Array unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308257/array-unique-values)

[Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery)

The closest I got was using the following code:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myJSONArr.length; i++) {
   if (myJSONArr[i + 1].name != myJSONArr[i].name) {
         results.push(myJSONArr[i]);
   }
}
```

But this always gives me an undefined error and if I put in code to check for the undefined error it leaves one from the list out. So for example it gets the following names:

```
Data Point Zeta
Data Point Alpha
Data Point Maverick
Data Point Delta
```

So Data Point Bravo never gets pushed to the array.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple check hash?

```
var data = [
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Zeta",
          "unit": "456456456"
    },
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Alpha",
          "unit": "345345"
    },
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Maverick",
          "unit": "453455"
    },
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Delta",
          "unit": "3534545"
    },
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Bravo",
          "unit": "534553455"
    },
    {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Data Point Bravo",
          "unit": "4356346436"
    }
];

var results = []; var checks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!checks[data[i].name]) {
        results.push(data[i]);
    }
    checks[data[i].name] = true;
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is always sorted by name like this, you can use your for loop with one addition: on the last element the if statement will throw the undefined error, because there is no next element (`myJSONArr[i + 1]`). Try something like this:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myJSONArr.length; i++) {
    if (i === myJSONArr.length - 1 || myJSONArr[i + 1].name != myJSONArr[i].name) {
        results.push(myJSONArr[i]);
    }
}
```