# array to set conversion works only for one dimensional array not for object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, set

I want to get unique entries from array which is showing different behaviour on 1d array and object array , I want to get unique entry from the object array
Similar question has already been asked [Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery) and [Array unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308257/array-unique-values) but they are different from my case , **I just want to ask why 1d array and object array behave differently when they are converted to set and back to array to get unique entries and what is the mistake I did**

My json array is like below

```js
    let arr=[{description: "d1", item_id: 298237, id: 298237, show_tag: 0, tags: "6,7,15,16,20"},
    {description: "d2", item_id: 297743, id: 297743, show_tag: 0, tags: "5,7,15,16,20"},
    {description: "d1", item_id: 298237, id: 298237, show_tag: 0, tags: "6,7,15,16,20"},
    {description: "d2", item_id: 297743, id: 297743, show_tag: 0, tags: "5,7,15,16,20"}
    ]
 let u=Array.from(new Set(arr));
 console.log(u);
    
 //it works for normal 1d array
 let arr1=[2,3,5,6,2,3];
 let u1=Array.from(new Set(arr1));
 console.log(u1);
```

and I want to get uniques only.Here is my attempt

Comment: Because every object is unique, even if they have the same property values. See: `console.log({} === {})` is `false` which means that two empty objects are not equal.

Comment: Yeah, `2 === 2`, `{} !== {}`, so they `Set` is doing just what it is supposed to do.